# Should I avoid refs in favor of e.target, for testing purposes?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs

I've frequently been writing components like this:

```
<input
    ref="ckbx"
    type="checkbox"
    checked={this.props.checked}
    onChange={() => this.props.onChange(this.refs.ckbx.checked)}
/>
```

However, I've now discovered that this is difficult to unit-test.
In particular, when using either `Simulate.change` or `Simulate.click`, the callback is passed the initial value of the checkbox instead of the new value (as happens in the browser).
This behavior persists when I add `{ target: { checked: false } }` as the second argument to each `Simulate` call.

It works if I instead use

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={this.props.checked}
    onChange={e => this.props.onChange(e.target.checked)}
/>
```

So, my questions are

- Is this the **preferred** way to write input logic?
- Is this the **only** unit-testable way to write input logic?
  It really doesn't seem that flexible (what if I need to consider multiple refs?).
- Can I get my existing method to work?
- Should I change all my components?
  (Not difficult, but I don't want to do it if there's a better way.)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) they only use `e.target` and I always use input with `e.target` as well.
I strongly recommend you avoid using `refs` in React as much as possible. First of all, because React team calls it "an escape hatch". Moreover - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#summary

With using `e.target` you can Simulate event and it should work perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not satisfied with this, particularly because the docs [also state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) that "Performing DOM measurements almost always requires reaching out to a 'native' component such as `<input />` and accessing its underlying DOM node using a ref. Refs are one of the only practical ways of doing this reliably."